# Godot 4.1, why is the debugger not working?

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot4

For some reason the debugger output of my project just stopped working, and I get this error:

"_debug_messenger_callback: GENERAL - Message Id Number: 0 | Message Id Name: Loader Message ReadDataFilesInRegestry: Registry lookup failed to get layer manifest files.
Object - 1
Object[0] - VK_OBJECT_TYPE_INSTANCE, Handle 2386414936624
<C++ source> drivers/vulkan/vulkan_context.cpp:264 @ _debug_messenger_callback()"

I have no idea what to do with this.

My remote port is 6007 (which I think is the default), and I've never changed it.

I'm at a complete loss at what to do, and desperately need the console working again.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The only thing I can tell is that it is Vulkan related. Was there a driver/display device change?

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure what you mean by that (I'm very new to Godot). I did try changing the renderer from mobile to forward+, then back around the time this happened. I'm not sure if that's related.

Comment: I just tried switching to compatibility. The error is gone, but the debugger still isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so the answer is that I'm a complete moron!

I forgot I had disabled printed messages in the output.

I'll leave this up (despite how embarrassing it is), since it would still be nice to know what the error message in my original question is, and in case anyone else makes the same mistake as me.

At least I know I picked the right user name.